# How to print JSON data from google maps directions api on html page

Tags: javascript, json, rest, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I want to print the status and other variables in console of the maps 
api. 
The XHR object I created contains the data in variables but when I print 
xhr.status it says 0. But in console When I opened XHR object status is 
200. 
I exactly want to print the whole data returning from maps API. I even 
enabled CORS request.

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button></br>

</form>
<p id="demo"> hello</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {

  var slat = document.getElementById("slat").value;

  var slong = document.getElementById("slong").value;
  var dlat = document.getElementById("dlat").value;
  var dlong = document.getElementById("dlong").value;
  //xhr object for sending request to maps api
  var xhr= 
  createCORSRequest('GET',"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?
  origin=75+9th+Ave+New+York,+NY&destination=Boston&key=My key was here");
  if (!xhr) {
    throw new Error('CORS not supported');
  }

  console.log(xhr); // seeing the  xhr object
  console.log(xhr.response); // trying to print xhr response but nothing is coming
  console.log(xhr.status); // 0 is being displayed as status but 200 is there in xhr object
  console.log(xhr.responseType);

}
```

Comment: Well from the code I'm surprise you can even call it since your `console.log()`-ing it outside the function scope...

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are creating an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest); you need to provide `onload` handler and the attributes you want will be available within the handler:

```
xhr.onload=function(e) {
        console.log(xhr.response);
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(xhr.responseType);
}
```

Note that I assume you are sending it with `xhr.send()`.

If you look at [developer's guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) provided by google, the response json object contains an array called `routes`. You should access the first route with `xhr.response.routes[0]` and this json object contains `summary` and `legs` array properties as follows:

```
"routes": [ {
    "summary": "I-40 W",
    "legs": [ {
      "steps": [ {
        "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
        "start_location": {
          "lat": 41.8507300,
          "lng": -87.6512600
        },
        "end_location": {
          "lat": 41.8525800,
          "lng": -87.6514100
        },
        "polyline": {
          "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOwHJy@P"
        },
        "duration": {
          "value": 19,
          "text": "1 min"
        },
        "html_instructions": "Head \u003cb\u003enorth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eS Morgan St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eW Cermak Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
        "distance": {
          "value": 207,
          "text": "0.1 mi"
        }
      },
      ...
      ... additional steps of this leg
    ...
    ... additional legs of this route
      "duration": {
        "value": 74384,
        "text": "20 hours 40 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 2137146,
        "text": "1,328 mi"
      },
      "start_location": {
        "lat": 35.4675602,
        "lng": -97.5164276
      },
      "end_location": {
        "lat": 34.0522342,
        "lng": -118.2436849
      },
      "start_address": "Oklahoma City, OK, USA",
      "end_address": "Los Angeles, CA, USA"
    } ],
```

So this is up to you to extract relevant information from the response. You can benefit from the following simple [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_html_set) to bind the data to a `<p>` tag or any dom element you like within your html. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Now how do I get the exact the directions from the JSON response to my html file. Also How do I print the response in HTML